# Neo4j add unique value to array property

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following code:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM
'file:///C:/Users/Zona/Documents/Neo4j/check/import/result1.csv' AS line1
MERGE (p:Person {forename:line1.forename, surname:line1.surname})
ON CREATE SET p.compNumber = 
CASE
WHEN NOT EXISTS (p.compNumber) THEN line1.CompanyNumber 
WHEN EXISTS(p.compNumber) AND line1.CompanyNumber NOT IN p.compNumber THEN p.compNumber + line1.CompanyNumber
ELSE p.compNumber
END
ON MATCH SET p.compNumber = 
CASE
WHEN NOT EXISTS (p.compNumber) THEN line1.CompanyNumber 
WHEN EXISTS(p.compNumber) AND line1.CompanyNumber NOT IN p.compNumber THEN p.compNumber + line1.CompanyNumber
ELSE p.compNumber
END
```

What I am trying to do is to add `compNumber` array property to the `Person` nodes. So, I am checking if the property `compNumber` already exists in the node and if the new value that needs to be added is not already in the property. If the property does not exist, it creates it with the desired value and if exists and the value is not in the array, then the value is appended to the array.

This query produces an error. Does anyone know what am I doing wrong here and is there a prettier solution to my problem?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use a :Company or :CompanyNumber node connected to a :Person instead of storing it in an array on the :Person object? This will also be useful if you need to lookup :Persons by the company number later.

Comment: What I have right now is :Company with nodes that have property `companyNumber` and thought about adding `compNumber` property to :Person and then matching them based on the number. Are you suggesting to remove the `companyNumber` property from :Company and create a new node that has `companyNumber` as property and then connect `:Person` and `:Company` nodes to that node like this `(:Person)->[:HAS_NUMBER]->(:CompanyNumber)<-[:HAS_NUMBER]-(:Company)` ?

Comment: No, that seems a bit excessive. If you already have :Company nodes with companyNumber property (I'm assuming there's a unique constraint on :Company(companyNumber)), then there's no reason you create relationships between :Persons and :Companies with the given companyNumber instead of storing companyNumbers in an array. It almost sounds like you're coming from a relational database with foreign keys between tables. In Neo4j, foreign keys tend not to be used, relationships between nodes are preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my previous comments, it sounds like you're trying to setup foreign keys between :Persons and :Companies. In graph databases, foreign keys tend not to be used, as the concept of relationships between nodes replaces them.

I would recommend abandoning the approach of keeping companyNumbers in arrays on :Person nodes, and instead, during processing, find the :Company node with that companyNumber (if it exists) and creating the relationship between the :Person and the :Company.

Let's assume there's a unique constraint on :Company(companyNumber).

A modified query might look something like this:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM
'file:///C:/Users/Zona/Documents/Neo4j/check/import/result1.csv' AS line1
MERGE (p:Person {forename:line1.forename, surname:line1.surname})
MERGE (c:Company {companyNumber:line1.CompanyNumber})
MERGE (p)-[:WorksFor]->(c)
```

You'll want to change :WorksFor to whatever relationship type makes the most sense, since you never provided the context of the relationship between :Persons and :Company nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Your `line1.CompanyNumber NOT IN p.compNumber` syntax is wrong. It should be `NOT line1.CompanyNumber IN p.compNumber`.

Also, the `ON CREATE` case can be greatly simplified, since we know in that case that `p.comNumber` does not exist:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///C:/Users/Zona/Documents/Neo4j/check/import/result1.csv' AS line1
MERGE (p:Person {forename:line1.forename, surname:line1.surname})
ON CREATE SET p.compNumber = line1.CompanyNumber
ON MATCH SET p.compNumber =
  CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS (p.compNumber) THEN line1.CompanyNumber
       WHEN EXISTS(p.compNumber) AND NOT line1.CompanyNumber IN p.compNumber THEN p.compNumber + line1.CompanyNumber
       ELSE p.compNumber END
```